# Migration for creating join table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, migration

There's a table in my SQL DB called "projects" and it has a column in it "categories" which is a varchar(255) representation of a php array `"['category_1', 'category_2', 'category_3']"` and what i'd like to do is put these categories into a separate table which would be made of a unique integer id in addition to the name of the category and then use a join table to connect it to "projects" in a many-to-many relationship.

So it would be a migration that would perform the following:

1. Create a join table called "categories_projects"
2. Create a table called "categories" that would be comprised of just a unique id and the title of the category
3. Insert into the categories a row for each so "category_1", "category_2", "category_3"
4. Look for any existing rows in the "projects" table and based on the varchar(255) field "category" mentioned above, create a row in the join table that would connect it to its respective category.
   What I have so far:

```
    <?php
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
    
    class CreateCategoriesTable extends Migration
    {
        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->unsignedInteger('parent_id')->nullable();
                $table->string('title');
                $table->timestamps();
                $table->softDeletes();
            });
            DB::table('categories')->insert(
                [
                  'title' => 'category_1'
                ], [
                  'title' => 'category_2'
                ], [
                  'title' => 'category_3'
                ], [
                  'title' => 'category_4'
                ], [
                  'title' => 'category_5'
                ]
            );
            Schema::create('categories_projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->unsignedInteger('project_id');
                $table->unsignedInteger('category_id');
                $table->timestamps();
                $table->softDeletes();
            });
            // This doesn't work but it's a representation of what I'm trying to do
            // $categories = DB::rawQuery('select * from categories');
            // foreach ($categories as $category) {
            //    $projects = DB::rawQuery('select * from projects where projects.category like %$category['title']');
            //    foreach($projects as $project) {
            //      DB::table(categories_projects)->insert(['project_id' => $project['id'], 'category_id' => $category['id']]);
            //    }
            //    
            // }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up going with, it seems like I answered my own question in the process of asking it but anyways:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('categories');
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
        DB::table('categories')->insert([
            ['title' => 'Addition'],
            ['title' => 'Bathrooms'],
            ['title' => 'Commercial'],
            ['title' => 'Community'],
            ['title' => 'Dental'],
            ['title' => 'Design & Construction'],
            ['title' => 'Facade'],
            ['title' => 'Home Design'],
            ['title' => 'Medical'],
            ['title' => 'Multi-Family'],
            ['title' => 'Office'],
            ['title' => 'Renovation'],
            ['title' => 'Residential'],
            ['title' => 'Restaurant'],
            ['title' => 'Retail'],
            ['title' => 'Student Housing']
        ]);
        Schema::create('categories_projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('project_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('category_id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
        $categories = DB::table("categories")->get();
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $category_id = $category->id;
            $projects = DB::table('projects')->where('categories', 'like', '%'.$category->title.'%')->get();
            $category_proj = [];
            foreach ($projects as $project) {
                $project_id = $project->id;
                $category_proj[] = ['project_id' => $project_id, 'category_id' => $category_id];
            }
            DB::table('categories_projects')->insert($category_proj);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('categories_projects');
        Schema::dropIfExists('categories');
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

*If both sides of your categories name in your main table are surrounded by single quotes (such as 'category_1')*

```php
$categories = DB::rawQuery("select * from categories");
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $projects = DB::rawQuery("select * from projects where category like '%''" . $category["title"] . "''%' ");

    foreach($projects as $project) {
        DB::table('categories_projects')->insert(['project_id' => $project['id'], 'category_id' => $category['id']]);
    }

}
```

Comment: I should note that the commented section is just a rough idea of what I'm looking to do but that `DB::rawQuery` is not really the exact method to return an array in this way.